# open file upload dialog on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I have to open file upload dialog by clicking some other button i.e i am hiding file upload control(visibility:hidden) and on clicking of some other button i want to open that dialog.
Below is the code which i am having:

```
<input type="file" style="visibility: hidden;" />
```

Below is the javascript:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('input[type=file]').click();
});
```

It is working fine in Firefox 4 and IE8 but in chrome12 it is not working i.e the dialog is not being opened. Any idea why?

Answer (score 8):

Tested today the simple code given in the question and the situation has changed:

- IE9: works
- Chrome23: works
- Firefox15: works

There is just one catch - on IE the .click() is a blocking operation while on other browsers it is not.

Comment: can you explain more what do u mean by  blocking operation?

Comment: `fileElement.click(); var x = fileElement.value;` - on IE this will work as expected, but on other browsers `x` will be empty.

Answer (score 5):

In your example, your file input did not have an id, yet you are trying to reference it with #input.  This works for me:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('input[type=file]').click();
});
```

Comment: actually this doesn't work as of now, either from updates to jquery either from browser updates

Answer (score 0):

You should position input[file] just above your custom control. And then bind to it`s onclick.

Also make in it bigger font-size, as only this way you can increase it's height.